# AGXGLDriver 0x00000001a4cbb228 glrKillClient + 464 (agxu_kill_client.cpp:175) crash

Tags: swift

Recently, I get these crashes from users. I cannot figure out the root cause, please help. I'm using WebView (UIWebView for iOS 8 and WkWebview for iOS 9 and above), some javascript function will be called in runtime. I think this can be related to the crash but I cannot figure it out.

```html
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000001
VM Region Info: 0x1 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4304863231
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                 0000000100970000-0000000100974000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ....app/test123456]

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  3
```

```html
Thread 3 name:
Thread 3 Crashed:
0   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib     0x00000001a0a98ee8 gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient + 12 (gpui_client_io.c:77)
1   AGXGLDriver                    0x00000001a4cbb228 glrKillClient + 464 (agxu_kill_client.cpp:175)
2   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib     0x00000001a0a99ecc gpusSubmitDataBuffers + 176 (gpui_context.c:0)
3   AGXGLDriver                    0x00000001a4cbc724 SubmitPackets(AGXContextRec*) + 296 (agxu_gl_command.cpp:93)
4   WebCore                        0x000000018d96435c WebCore::GraphicsContext3D::reshape(int, int) + 552 (GraphicsContext3DOpenGLCommon.cpp:376)
5   WebCore                        0x000000018e5f2198 WebCore::WebGLRenderingContextBase::initializeNewContext() + 888 (WebGLRenderingContextBase.cpp:598)
6   WebCore                        0x000000018e5f1ba4 WebCore::WebGLRenderingContextBase::WebGLRenderingContextBase(WebCore::HTMLCanvasElement&, WTF::Ref<WebCore::GraphicsContext3D>&&, WebCore::GraphicsContext3DAttributes) + 544 (WebGLRenderingContextBase.cpp:497)
7   WebCore                        0x000000018e5ec8dc WebCore::WebGLRenderingContext::WebGLRenderingContext(WebCore::HTMLCanvasElement&, WTF::Ref<WebCore::GraphicsContext3D>&&, WebCore::GraphicsContext3DAttributes) + 44 (WebGLRenderingContext.cpp:74)
8   WebCore                        0x000000018e5f1160 WebCore::WebGLRenderingContextBase::create(WebCore::HTMLCanvasElement&, WebCore::GraphicsContext3DAttributes&, WTF::String const&) + 956 (memory:3006)
9   WebCore                        0x000000018d9a3b28 WebCore::HTMLCanvasElement::getContextWebGL(WTF::String const&, WebCore::GraphicsContext3DAttributes&&) + 152 (HTMLCanvasElement.cpp:326)
10  WebCore                        0x000000018dd1a740 WebCore::JSHTMLCanvasElement::getContext(JSC::ExecState&) + 312 (JSHTMLCanvasElementCustom.cpp:71)
11  WebCore                        0x000000018d531fc0 WebCore::jsHTMLCanvasElementPrototypeFunctionGetContext(JSC::ExecState*) + 168 (JSHTMLCanvasElement.cpp:258)
12  JavaScriptCore                 0x000000018c748eb4 llint_entry + 29668
13  JavaScriptCore                 0x000000018c748454 llint_entry + 27012
14  JavaScriptCore                 0x000000018c748454 llint_entry + 27012
15  JavaScriptCore                 0x000000018c748454 llint_entry + 27012
16  JavaScriptCore                 0x000000018c748454 llint_entry + 27012
17  JavaScriptCore                 0x000000018c741900 vmEntryToJavaScript + 272
18  JavaScriptCore                 0x000000018c620170 JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 184 (JITCode.cpp:81)
19  JavaScriptCore                 0x000000018c005294 JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 400 (Interpreter.cpp:971)
20  JavaScriptCore                 0x000000018c658a9c JSC::boundThisNoArgsFunctionCall(JSC::ExecState*) + 476 (JSBoundFunction.cpp:54)
21  JavaScriptCore                 0x000000018c741a48 vmEntryToNative + 280
22  JavaScriptCore                 0x000000018c0052dc JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 472 (Interpreter.cpp:973)
23  JavaScriptCore                 0x000000018c2693fc JSC::profiledCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::ProfilingReason, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&, WTF::NakedPtr<JSC::Exception>&) + 180 (CallData.cpp:40)
24  WebCore                        0x000000018e329308 WebCore::ScheduledAction::executeFunctionInContext(JSC::JSGlobalObject*, JSC::JSValue, WebCore::ScriptExecutionContext&) + 528 (JSMainThreadExecState.h:72)
25  WebCore                        0x000000018e328f44 WebCore::ScheduledAction::execute(WebCore::Document&) + 140 (ScheduledAction.cpp:126)
26  WebCore                        0x000000018d408260 WebCore::DOMTimer::fired() + 728 (DOMTimer.cpp:368)
27  WebCore                        0x000000018d407e18 WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFiredInternal() + 172 (ThreadTimers.cpp:118)
28  WebCore                        0x000000018d407d58 WebCore::timerFired(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) + 28 (MainThreadSharedTimerCF.cpp:74)
29  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001855a7dc0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28 (CFRunLoop.c:1832)
30  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001855a7ae4 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 864 (CFRunLoop.c:2415)
31  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001855a72e4 __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 248 (CFRunLoop.c:2562)
32  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001855a4ecc __CFRunLoopRun + 1928 (CFRunLoop.c:3083)
33  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001854c4c58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
34  WebCore                        0x000000018d43984c RunWebThread(void*) + 560 (WebCoreThread.mm:690)
35  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001852282b4 _pthread_body + 308 (pthread.c:740)
36  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000185228180 _pthread_start + 312 (pthread.c:799)
37  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000185226b74 thread_start + 4
```

Thank you very much.